# C# find installation directory of application

Tags: c#, windows, registry, installation

I build an application that's run setup files and automatically patch it after setup completes.

I use this registry key **HLKM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall** but some applications doesn't have this key.

How I can find installation directory?

Comment: You're trying to patch 3rd party applications? There's no requirement that any record be made of an install location. That said, it's a pretty poor application if it doesn't add an uninstall key.

Comment: Yes, I'm try to patch 3rd party applications, more than half of them has no registry key to save installation directory!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the VS Setup Project as your installer, then you can utilize [Custom Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as one method of getting information about the Setup environment.

With that said, I feel there might be a better way to accomplish your goals, and with more information I think we could help you get there.

**EDIT**

I think I follow you now.  If I were doing this I would first hard code the default setup location for each 3rd party app I'm packaging. If the user changes the default, it won't be found, so then prompt them for their new path.  Remember you can use [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) to get the actual location of Program Files (or other system folders), instead of assuming C:\.  For probably 99.9% of installations and users this method will complete without any extra user interaction.

Another option is to create your own installer for those 3rd party binaries that are being contrary. Of course you have to maintain updates too, but it sounds like you're already doing something like that with your patches.

Comment: there are multiple setup files that builds by various setup builders

Answer (score 2):

You could use `system` and `application` classes.

```
Application.ExecutablePath
```

For example you can get the full name of the directory containing your executable as follows:

```
string executableName = Application.ExecutablePath;
FileInfo executableFileInfo = new FileInfo(executableName);
string executableDirectoryName = executableFileInfo.DirectoryName;
```